# How do I use a for loop in a toolbar view?

Tags: arrays, swiftui, toolbar

I have written something like the code below. Creating a struct for menu information (MenuInfo) and created a few menu items in an array of MenuInfo's.  I'm now trying to walk over those to create the menus.  (For now just printing details from the array).  Code below is to show the concept and may not compile.  I get the following error:

> Static method 'buildExpression' requires that 'ToolbarItemGroup<Menu<Text, TupleView<(Button, Button, Divider, Button)>>>' conform to 'View'

Not sure what I have done wrong but the issue goes away when I comment out the entire ToolbarItemGroup -> for section.  The error prints next to the first ToolbarItemGroup which of course is correct and the error is not specific.

```
enum Tools {
   case a, b
}

struct MenuInfo {
  var name: String
  var image: String
  var tool: Tools

  init(_ name: String,_ image: String,_ tool: Tools ) {
     self.name      = name
     self.image     = image
     self.tool      = tool
  }
}

private var qMark = "questionmark"

//   Name           Image   Tool
var myMenu = [
   MenuInfo( "A",   qMark,  .a ),
   MenuInfo( "B",   qMark,  .b )
]

struct ContentView: View {
   @State private var curToolSet = ToolSet.eng
   @State private var curTool = Tools.arrow

   var body: some View {
       VStack {
           Text( "Content" )
               .toolbar {
                   ToolbarItemGroup {
                       Menu(content: {
                           Button( "Hi" ) { curToolSet = .eng }
                       }, label:{ Text( "Engineering" )})
                   }

//                  ToolbarItemGroup {
//                      for curMenu in myMenu {
//                          Button( curMenu.name, systemImage: curMenu.image ) {
//                          }
//                      }
//                  }
               }    // End toolbar  
       }    // End vStack
       .frame( height: 500 )
       .frame( width: 800 )
   }    //  End View

   private func selectTool() {
       print(" in selectTool ")
   }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a `for` loop, use `ForEach`:

```
ForEach(myMenu, id: \.name) { (curMenu) in
    Button(curMenu.name, systemImage: curMenu.image)
}
```

If the items in the array passed to `ForEach` conform to `Identifiable`, you can skip the `id:` argument. If they don't, you have to pass in the name of a property that `ForEach` can use as a unique identifier. (I just guessed that the `name` field is what you want here.)

Comment: Hummm, no... that doesn't work either.  I get Static method 'buildExpression' requires that 'Menu<Text, TupleView<(Button<Text>, Button<Text>, Divider, Button<Text>)>>' conform to 'CustomizableToolbarContent'.  I tried with and without ToolbarItemGroup.

Comment: Put the `ForEach` after your `Button("Hi)` line.

Comment: That doesn't work either:  Static method 'buildExpression' requires that 'ToolbarItemGroup<Menu<Text, TupleView<(Button<Text>, Button<Text>, Divider, Button<Text>)>>>' conform to 'View'.   Also as far as order I have a menu first on my Toolbar.  I want that first.

Comment: OK, I figured it out.  In my actual code I forgot the scope characters after the Botton() { }.  I figured that out by moving this code block to the top and then Swift was so kind to give me a valid error.  For some reason it calls this scoping section a parameter but I got the idea :).  The Button ( "Hi" ) was not required.  Thanks a bunch.   I'm learning new debugging techniques I've never used in Pascel, C, C++, Python or Java :)

Comment: Great! SwiftUI still has pretty poor debugging messages, and that can be frustrating even if you're a longtime Swift user.